# How to append special symbols to a textbox on click of respective button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Unable to add symbols to the textbox on click of symbols present inside the popover using jquery.

Onclick of edit symbol near textbox a popover containing symbol buttons appear.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="symboltext"> 
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="popbutton" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var popupElement = '<div class="btn-group" role="group"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="regbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="copyrightbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"><span></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="trademarkbtn"><sup>TM</sup></button></div>';

$('#popbutton').popover({
    animation: true,
    content: popupElement,
    html: true
});

$("#regbtn").click(function () {
    $("#symboltext").append("&#174;");
});

$("#copyrightbtn").click(function () {
    $("#symboltext").append("&#169;");
});

$("#trademarkbtn").click(function () {
    $("#symboltext").append("&#8482;");
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/9te4uk31/8/)

Comment: `$("symboltext")`, wrong selector...

Comment: not working after editing that

Comment: Too many things wrong in your code, se comment below first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to answer my question :)

Thanks @A.Wolff and @ahervin for your inputs

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="symboltext"> 
            <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="popbutton" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
       var popupElement = '<div class="btn-group" role="group"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="regbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="copyrightbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"><span></button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" id="trademarkbtn"><sup>TM</sup></button></div>';
var lastPoint = 0;
$('#popbutton').popover({
    animation: true,
    content: popupElement,
    html: true
});

function textbox() {
    var ctl = document.getElementById('symboltext');
    var startPos = ctl.selectionStart;
    var endPos = ctl.selectionEnd;
    lastPoint = startPos;
    return {
        s: startPos,
        e: endPos
    };
}

function getVal(insert) {
    var val = $("#symboltext").val();
    var index = textbox();
    val = val.slice(0, index.s) + insert + val.slice(index.s)
    lastPoint += 2;
    return val;
}

$(document).on('click', "#trademarkbtn", function () {
    var val = getVal("\u2122");
    var input = $("#symboltext");
    input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint;
});


$(document).on('click', "#regbtn", function () {
    var val = getVal("\u00AE");
    var input = $("#symboltext");
    input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint;
});

$(document).on('click', "#copyrightbtn", function () {
    var val = getVal("\u00A9");
    var input = $("#symboltext");
    input.val(val).focus();
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = lastPoint;
});
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/70tkhpvg/16/)

Comment: Works well but this will overwrite existing input, see http://jsfiddle.net/70tkhpvg/1/

Comment: oh,yes,but in your fiddle it's somewhat fine.I need it wherever the cursor is placed

Answer (score 2):

```
$("symboltext")
```

doesn't have the `#` selector
Try Changing to

`$("#symboltext")`

Also the buttons are generated dynamically so use

`$(document).on('click', "#trademarkbtn", function () {`

Edit: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9te4uk31/15/)

Comment: That's not the only issue. OP try to add content to void element, which cannot be done and bind events before elements available in the DOM

Comment: @IamRaviteja But input type text can only get text value set, how you are expecting it to get icon added? Maybe set background image instead

Comment: can't we add using HTML Character Entities as`&#174;` for registered trademark

Comment: @IamRaviteja I'm not sure but maybe EDIT: use character: `™` etc.. E.g: http://jsfiddle.net/9te4uk31/12/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9te4uk31/10/, Sort of like what @IamRaviteja said , perhaps float the icon at the end of the box?

Comment: I am getting it as text,i need it as a symbol @ahervin

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9te4uk31/14/ See I have put it in a input group span after the text? Still needs styling etc. but is this closer to what you want?